# Java: How to find matching String Template variables with parameters and replace by auto generated values

Tags: java, regex, lookup

In my java application, user can use my predefined variables sets like `RANDOM_ALPHANUMERIC(charLength)` Or `RANDOM_ALPHANUMERIC(minLength, maxLength)`.

Let's say the User defined the below by using the variables

```
something<$$RANDOM_ALPHANUMERIC(8)$$> something <$$RANDOM_ALPHANUMERIC(5,8)$$> something
```

I need my Java program to parse the above String and find the `RANDOM_ALPHANUMERIC(charLength)`, `RANDOM_ALPHANUMERIC(minLength, maxLength)` patterns and replace them by appropriate values.

I tried to find the StrSubstitutor from commons lang, but can't find much helpful.

Please advice how to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean by "variable" set? I don't get your question. Most likely, some code would be very helpful to better understand your problem. Are you saying that the user can write "scripts", and that your java program should be interpreting those scripts?

Comment: Yes, correct. User can post the scripts and my program to interpret that and resolve the variables used. Consider RANDOM_ALPHANUMERIC is a variable and charLength, min, max as their parameters. I need to resolve and replace those placeholders with what exactly asked

Comment: Well, then you should probably step back and learn how to write a reasonable parser. There is much more to this topic than just recognizing predefined names and mapping them to functionality. To be more precise: does your program **interpret** the user input (meaning: execute); or is it just doing some kind of "translation" to replace strings with other strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex would be: `RANDOM_ALPHANUMERIC\((\d+),?(\d+)?\)`
http://regexr.com/3aqbm

The problem is, since the name of the function is the same that you need to know if there is a second parameter or not.
Solutions are either:

- two distinct method names
- parsing the string twice or parsing the string for `RANDOM_ALPHANUMERIC(` and then checking if there is one or two parameters
- giving the regex group a name

Comment: That matches multiple commas in a row.